# How to move UITableView vertically

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have created small iPhone application. I put UITableView and put some UIView inside cells. I added functionality to move view in cell horizontally. Now I want to add logic to move whole UITableView vertically if I move my finger vertically in my UIView. That is my code:

```
-(void)moveView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[self superview]];
        prevPos = location;
        startPosition = self.frame.origin.x;

    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[self superview]];
        float delX =  location.x - prevPos.x;
        float delY =  location.y - prevPos.y;
        if(delX > 0 && delX * delX > delY * delY)
        {
            CGPoint np = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x+delX, self.frame.origin.y);
            CGRect fr = self.frame;
            fr.origin = np;
            self.frame = fr;
            prevPos = location;
        }
        else if(delX * delX < delY * delY)
        {

        }
    }
    else if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
            [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed ||
            [recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

        CGRect rect = self.frame;
        rect.origin.x = startPosition;
        self.frame = rect;
        startPosition = 0;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

What code should I put in this condition:  `else if(delX * delX < delY * delY)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll a TableView, you need to alter the TableView's contentOffset property.

Look at the [setContentOffset:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setContentOffset%3aanimated%3a) documentation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but not as standart behaviour of tableView. Is it possible to pass control to UITableView?

Comment: Why do you want to scroll the tableView yourself? Isn't the tableView scrolling itself? If not why?

Comment: I don't know how explain it in English. If I scroll table view as usual - it works. If I am trying scrool table view by finger, but finger on UIView in tablecell. This view has gesture recognizer which prevent standart table view scrolling. I need to pass control to table view if finger moves vertically.